# Integrating Cloudify with vCloud

Tags: vmware, jclouds, cloudify

I am working on using Cloudify for vCloud. So far the information I gathered , this intgegration is possible as jCloud has interfaces for vCloud too. I am yet to explore the jCloud too. I am looking for if any effort has been put to integrate Cloudify with vCloud. Any pointers to documentation or earlier Qs/blogs which I couldn't find myself will be valuable.
Thanks
Raghavendra

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed discussion about this [here](https://cloudifysource.zendesk.com/entries/27053676-Looking-for-Vcloud-parameters-for-vcloud-cloud-groovy-and-vcloud-cloud-properties-file)